# Catch exception in calling method within method chaining in C#

Tags: c#, exception

In recent interview, Interviewer ask me following question in C#.

Suppose we have 5 methods m1, m2, m3, m4, m5 and m1 call m2, m2 calls m3, and so on. But when exception occurs in m5 we must catch in m4, when exception occurs in m4 we must catch in m3, and so on. At first, I think it simple way, just include try-catch block in all methods excepts last method m5. But within seconds, i understand that this solution will not work.

```
    public static void m1()
    {
        try
        {
            m2();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Catch m1");
        }
    }
    public static void m2()
    {
        try
        {
            m3();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Catch m2");
        }
    }
    public static void m3()
    {
        try
        {
            m4();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Catch m3");
        }
    }
    public static void m4()
    {
        try
        {
            m5();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Catch m4");
        }
    }
    public static void m5()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(50 / i);
    }
```

I also tried with many approaches, searched on internet but can't find proper solution. Please suggest correct way of doing this functionality.

Comment: Seems like an odd question, but in your catch block you could throw the exception, which will bubble up to the next calling method.  I.e., `m4` has an exception, and throws it.  `m3` can catch that exception in it's try-catch block.

Comment: Your problem description is vague. In one sense, a method can be said to throw an exception if the exception occurs at any time while that method is executing, even if the exception occurs in a callee of that method. What is it about your simple approach that doesn't work. Please be specific.

Comment: Hmm... I don't see why this would not work yet....at the moment it looks like it does exactly what you want. Just remember that when you add code to - say- `m3`, add it _outside_ the `try` block.

Comment: Maybe you can write your own exception. For Example `M5Exception` and `M4Exception` and so on...

Comment: Your approach will work. You just assume that for example m4 calls ONLY m5, which is not necessary true. m4 calls m5 and also performs other things which might throw. You need to catch only exceptions from m5.

Comment: I seems to be working. I would try put some errorable code between try and catch blocks in each method.

Comment: Since this was an interview question, I hope you went on to explain why this design is poor, and that in general you should only catch the specific exception types you can handle...